# Python code to extract similar strings from 2 lists

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement

I have 2 lists of Names of players from 2 different sources.

`names1 = ['C.J. McCollum', 'Metta World', 'LeBron James', 'Stephen Curry']`

`names2 = ['Metta World Peace', 'Steph Curry', 'Kevin Durant', 'CJ McCollum']`

The problem here is that though they are the same players, there are some difference in the way their names are mentioned in the 2 sources. I used the following code the find the similar names (all characters in `names1` should exist in `names2`):

```
idx = np.zeros(3)
i = 0
for x, y in enumerate(names1):
    for z, w in enumerate(names2):
        if y in w:
            idx[i] = x
            i = i+1
```

For each iteration of `names1` the code among all the iterations of `names2` and outputs the index of the entry that is similar the the entry in `names2`. `idx` is a list that should contain the index of the similar strings. `i` is the the index of `idx`. Every time a similar string is found, it is stored in `idx` and `i` is increased by 1 so that the next entry found would be recorded in index `i+1` of `idx`.

Expected Answer:
`idx` = [0, 1, 3]

However I get the following error:
`list assignment index out of range`

How can I fix the code and is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: even that you don't had an error,you result will be an empty array or all zeros in your case, and I think your are looking for `y in w` and regarding your question I don't think there is a general solution for finding similar string without some base rules

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. I have updated my question. (I apologise for any inconveniences, I'm still new to Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt (here I considered that only the changes like M.C = MC, the uses of majuscule and minuscule, and a Levenshtein distance inferior to 2 is accepted to consider two names are the same):

```py
import numpy as np


def levenshtein_distance(v, w):
    n, m = len(v), len(w)
    M = np.zeros((n+1, m+1))
    for i in range(n+1):
        M[i, 0] = i
    for j in range(m+1):
        M[0, j] = j
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(1, m + 1):
            if v[i-1] == w[j-1]:
                M[i, j] = min(M[i-1, j] + 1, M[i, j-1] + 1, M[i-1, j-1])
            else:
                M[i, j] = min(M[i-1, j] + 1, M[i, j-1] + 1, M[i-1, j-1] + 1)
    return M[n, m]

def norm_names(x):
    # more names normalization can be added here
    return x.replace(".", "").lower()

names1 = ['C.J. McCollum', 'Metta World Peace', 'LeBron James', 'Stephen Curry']
names2 = ['Metta World Peace', 'Steph Curry', 'Kevin Durant', 'CJ McCollum']

names1 = list(map(norm_names, names1))
names2 = list(map(norm_names, names2))

indices = []
for i, name in enumerate(names1):
    for name2 in names2:
         indices += [i] if levenshtein_distance(name, name2) <= 2 else []
```

this will return `[0, 1, 3]`

Comment: Would this work for Steph Curry and Stephen Curry ?

Comment: yep, you can play with levenshtein distance in this [website](https://planetcalc.com/1721/)

Answer (score 1):

you are getting error because of    y in z: ,you can use y in w:
also you can do some formatting like removing '.' before comparing , and then you can use any string similarity algo like Levenshtein distance , to find similar strings ,
"pip install python-Levenshtein"

```
import numpy as np
import Levenshtein as ld

names1 = ['C.J. McCOllum', 'Metta World Peace', 'LeBron James', 'Stephen 
Curry']

names2 = ['Metta World Peace', 'Steph Curry', 'Kevin Durant', 'CJ McCollum']
idx = np.zeros(3)
i = 0
similarity_index =3
for x, y in enumerate(names1):
y=y.replace('.','')

for z, w in enumerate(names2):
    w= w.replace('.','')
    if ld.distance(y,w) < similarity_index:
        idx[i] = x
        i = i+1


 print(idx)
```

Comment: for these I have mentioned some algo can be used like Levenshtein distance  to calculate similarity between to strings , and some threshold distance value can be set to consider to strings similar .

Comment: it's better if you post the implementation in your answer